# What does this mean: "understanding you is like smelling the colour 9"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, sense-verbs

I saw a quote that read as

> "understanding you is like smelling the colour 9"

what does it mean?

As it suggests it may mean finding something or someone hard to understand but why it's called *smelling the colour 9*?

What's the origin of this saying?

A descriptive information will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the number 9 has no intrinsic colour, and colours have no intrinsic smell, the phrase "smelling the colour 9" is a [category error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake). In other words, the intent conveyed is that the phrase is not easy (or it is impossible) to understand. There is a condition called [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), but it is not a good fit in this context.

The simile draws the parallel to understanding someone, so the sentence means that the speaker doesn't understand the person he or she is speaking to.

Comment: I immediately thought of "synesthesia" when I smelt the tone of your tasty answer. :)

Comment: The peculiar phrasing of the statement indicates much more than the fact that the speaker doesn't understand who he's speaking to - it suggests that *no one* could understand this person, and any attempt to do so is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @NuclearWang The OP's quote sounds like an interpersonal interaction. Even saying that 'no one could understand him/her' would likely be an expression of the speaker's personal frustration at him/her.

Answer (score 3):

Christian musician Chris Rice wrote a song (and album) entitled "Smell the Color 9".  I'm not sure if it was just meant to be a silly song, or if it actually had some underlying (most likely Christian spiritual) meaning.  You can google the lyrics and try to figure that out.  But yeah, I'm pretty sure that's where the phrase "Smell the Color 9" originated.

Comment: Chris Rice actually answers the OP in the last lines of his lyrics:

"Sometimes finding You is like trying to smell the color 9. 9's not a color and even if it were you can't smell a color. That's my point exactly"

His lyric also says "he count count up pretty high"

In other words, it's an incomprehensible task: like *counting* (holding, seeing or having) infinity.

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused I don't know anything about Chris Rice and "smelling the color 9" rings no bells with me as a practicing Christian. However it is an awful lot like a Zen koan, a question with no logical answer intended to shock the adherent's mind into stopping so that the spirit can see the higher truth. This suggests to me that Rice is following a path of Christian mysticism at a sufficiently advanced level that his practice is growing close to that of advanced Zen. If my interpretation is correct you will find no logical meaning for the phrase, that's the point.

Comment: @BoldBen I think the best answer to the question about meaning is to read the actual lyrics.  I don't think it's a koan at all. It's a statement of futility. This is one stanza - I've added some parenthetical remarks:
  'Cause I can sniff (SMELL), I can see (PERCEIVE COLOR)
   I can count up pretty high (THINK ABSTRACTLY) 
   But these faculties aren't getting me
   any close to the sky (HEAVEN/GOD/UNDERSTANDING)
   But my heart of faith keeps poundin'
   So I know I'm doin' fine
   **But sometimes finding You
   Is just like trying to
   Smell the color nine**

Comment: @SteventheEasilyAmused That's the point about koans. The illogical question (like "what is the sound of one hand clapping") demonstrates the impossibility of using logic to gain true understanding. That's just what Chris Rice is doing with that line except that he's not slapping the neophyte into the mud when the neophyte gets the answer wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The number nine is often assiciated with eternity. See infinity of 9 on u-tube. Could be Chris Rice is only giving attention to behavior in light of human arrogance.